# Proving pullback of projection to quotient manifold is always injective on de Rham cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

I found the following result on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#The_n-torus):

> We can also find explicit generators for the de Rham cohomology of the torus directly using differential forms. Given a quotient manifold ${\displaystyle \pi :X\to X/G}$ and a differential form ${\displaystyle \omega \in \Omega ^{k}(X)}$ we can say that $\omega $ is ${\displaystyle G}$-invariant if given any diffeomorphism induced by ${\displaystyle G}$, ${\displaystyle \cdot g:X\to X}$ we have ${\displaystyle (\cdot g)^{*}(\omega )=\omega }$. In particular, the pullback of any form on ${\displaystyle X/G}$ is ${\displaystyle G}$-invariant. Also, the pullback is an injective morphism.

which states that the pullback $\pi^*: X/G \to X$ is injective. I was able to prove this but only in the case that the group $G$ is finite (it's somewhat of an "averaging" argument). But I can't see how to prove it in this general case (the "averaging" argument breaks down since a sum of infinite terms is not defined). I'd really appreciate some help on this!

Comment: can you convert the sum in your averaging argument to an integral ?

Comment: @hunter I don't see how. The averaging argument is the same as the one given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368210/finite-universal-covering-induces-injective-maps-on-cohomology

Comment: You want/need $G$ compact, and then @hunter’s comment applies.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you please elaborate a little more? How would I turn that sum into an integral if $G$ is compact, and why do we need compactness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $G$ is compact, take a basis of left-invariant $1$-forms, wedge them to get a left-invariant volume form $dV(g)$, and given any $k$-form $\omega$, the averaged form
$$\tilde\omega = \frac 1{\text{vol}(G)}\int_G L_g^*\omega\,dV(g)$$
is $G$-invariant. What's more, you can check that $\omega$ is closed/exact if and only if $\tilde\omega$ is closed/exact. So there's a unique invariant form in every cohomology class of $M$.

(Without compactness, the integral won't make sense, and nor will the volume.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it! I had been thinking about your comment for a while now but hadn't been able to get to this, your answer is perfect.